# Calling static generic methods

Tags: java, generics, static, type-inference

I have come across a curious situation involving static generic methods. This is the code:

```
class Foo<E>
{
    public static <E> Foo<E> createFoo()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Bar<E>
{
    private Foo<E> member;

    public Bar()
    {
        member = Foo.createFoo();
    }
}
```

How come I don't have to specify any type arguments in the expression `Foo.createFoo()`? Is this some kind of type inference? If I want to be explicit about it, how can I specify the type argument?

Comment: I would recommend you to change type parameter E of createFoo method. Because , type parameter E of class Foo is different than type parameter E of method createFoo().

Comment: @GurselKoca He could explicitly do member = Foo.<E>createFoo(); requiring them to be the same as compile time.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Yes, this is type inference based on the target of the assignment, as per [JLS section 15.12.2.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.8). To be explicit, you'd call something like:

```
Foo.<String>createFoo();
```

Comment: Or, as in my case: `Foo.<E>createFoo();` Thank you :)

Comment: How come this also works without the assignment? That is, the *statement* `Foo.createFoo();` compiles just fine...? Is this due to type erasure?

Comment: @FredOverflow without assignment `E` is "inferred" to be `Object`

Comment: New link location would probably be: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2

Comment: A different way to specify the type of `E` would be to define `createFoo()` take an argument of type `Class<E>` (so it would be `createFoo(Class<E> type)`), and call it with `createFoo(String.class)`

Comment: The complete syntax for invoking this method:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html