# Returning a child class

Tags: java, entity

Sorry for the vague title, I am not quite sure how to explain my problem.

I am working on creating an Entity Component System (ECS) and I have run into a bit of a snag. I have a function called `getComponent()`, and its job is to get a specific component from the given entity using the given component class (In this case, the `Name` component). So far, I can match up the `component` and the `componentClass` to return the correct component. Here is the function:

```
public static Component getComponent(int id, Class<? extends Component> componentClass){
    ArrayList<Component> entity = getEntity(id);
    for(Component component : entity){
        if(component.getClass() == componentClass){
            return component;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

My problem lies with the type casting of the return component. I'll give a quick example. In my `Namer` class, which manages all `Name` components, I want to loop through the entity database, get the entity's `Name` component, perform logic, and then continue. The issue is that in order to get data from the `Name`, I have to cast the component like so:

```
int entity = i;
Name n = (Name)Game.getComponent(entity, Name.class);
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
int entity = i;
Name n = Game.getComponent(entity, Name.class);
n.test = "Bob Binley"
```

I understand that it is a strange "problem" because it works just fine, but I don't feel comfortable leaving the code like this. Considering that the `getComponent()` function is going to be called alot, using alot of different `Component`'s, I would rather not have to worry about casting the component type every time I wish to use it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to do this:

```
Name n = Game.getComponent(entity, Name.class);
```

`getComponent(e,cls)` returns a `Component`, not a `Name`. How can you expect *not* to cast? You can, however, define `getComponent` to return a `C` where `C extends Component`.

```
public static <C extends Component> C getComponent(int id, Class<C> componentClass)  {
```

And then you can call it with without any casting:

```
Name n = ClassName.getComponent(entity, Name.class);
```

As mentioned by Tim B in his answer, casting may still be necessary in the `getComponent` function body.

Here is a related question: *[Calling static generic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297978/calling-static-generic-methods)*

And some more information: *https://www.google.com/search?q=calling+static+functions+with+generics*

Comment: The second argument should be of type Class<T>, which would allow the compiler to infer the generic type and not type `.<Name>`... just like in Tim B.'s answer.

Comment: Thanks alot, this is what I was looking for. To clarify, I had already tried changing the return value to `<? extends Component>`, But I guess that wasn't possible. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, you just need to change the generics in your method signature slightly:

```
public static <T extends Component> T getComponent(int id, Class<T> componentClass){
```

Now Generics knows that your getComponent method returns an object of type T and there is no need to cast when calling getComponent - although your implementation of getComponent may still need the cast inside.