# Generic method without class type?

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to call a method and provide the type parameter of the desired object as a parameter? Without having to create a sourrounding class with that generic type?

Example:

```
public static ItemReader<T> getItemReader(Class<T> type) {
    return new ItemReader<T>();
}


MyUtil.getItemReader(String.class);
```

Comment: You can use `public static <T> ItemReader<T> getFoo(Bar baz){}`, but the compiler still needs a way to determine which type `T` refers to, so you can hardly avoid the parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling static generic methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297978/calling-static-generic-methods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to call the method this way:

```
public static <T> ItemReader<T> getItemReader() {
    return new ItemReader<T>();
}

ItemReader<String> itemR = MyUtil.getItemReader();
```

You don't need `Class<T>` parameter.

Comment: In this case you don't even have to explicitly give the String param. ItemReader<String> itemR = MyUtil.getItemReader(); should be enough