# Check in Eclipse which type a Generic works with

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, generics, wildcard

```
class A {};
class B extends A {};
class C extends B {};
class D extends B {};
class E {};

class X {
    public static <T> T f(T[] a, Field<? extends T> b) { return null; }
    public static <T> T[] g(Field<? extends T> a, Field<? super T> b) { return null; }
```

Field is just a interface. When I got some Instructions like,

```
A a = X.f(new B[3], new FieldFix<D>(8));
```

I know this works, because the Generic Type T, will be A because D extends B and B extends A, so it's a pretty legit allocation.

But I got some different where I'm pretty unsure about the Type of T and can't explain to myself why this works or doesn't. So is there a way to see the Type? I already played with the Debugger, but I never really used it so I'm not very familiar with this.

Added:

```
public interface Field<T> {
    int size();
    T get(int i);
    T set(int i, T e); }

public class FieldFix<T> implements Field<T> {
    private T[] a;
    public FieldFix(int size) {
        T[] tmp = (T[])new Object[size]; a = tmp; }
    public int size() { return a.length; }
    public T get(int i) {
        try {
            return a[i];
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { ... }
    }
    public T set(int i, T e) {
         try {
            T result = a[i];
            a[i] = e;
            return result;
         } catch(ArrayIndex...) { ... }
    }
```

And this are all Instructions I got, some of them should work and some not

```
    A x01 = X.f(new B[3], new FieldFix<D>(8));
    Object[] x02 = X.f(new C[2], new FieldFix<D[]>(8));
    Feld x03 = X.f(new FieldFix[4], new FieldFix<FieldFix<A>>(8));
    A[] x05 = X.g(new FieldFix<B>(8), new FieldFix<B>(8));
    B[] x06 = X.g(new FieldFix<B>(8), new FieldFix<A>(8));
    C[] x07 = X.g(new FieldFix<B>(8), new FieldFix<A>(8));
    C[] x08 = X.g(new FieldFix<C>(8), new FieldFix<A>(8));
    C[] x09 = X.g(new FieldFix<A>(8), new FieldFix<C>(8));
    C[] x10 = X.g(new FieldFix<D>(8), new FieldFix<B>(8));
    Object x11 = X.g(new FieldFix<B>(8), new FieldFix<D>(8));
    B[] x12 = X.g(new FieldFix<A>(8), new FieldFix<Object>(8));
    A[] x13 = X.g(new FieldFix<B>(8), new FieldFix<Object>(8));
    Object x14 = X.g(new FieldFix<C[]>(8), new FieldFix<A[]>(8));
    Object x15 = X.g(new FieldFix<Field<C>>(8), new FieldFix<Field<A>>(8));
    Object x16 = X.g(new FieldFix<Field<C>>(8), new FieldFix<Field>(8));
```

Like x09, x11, x15 Eclipse tells me that I'm using wrong Arguments and for the other ones I like to check if my explanation of why this works is right, because sometimes I get very confused with this Generics and Wildcard stuff. So when I got

```
A[] a = X.g(new FieldFix<B>(8), new FeldFix<B>(8));
```

, I got it like this: because of  B can become B, C or D. And  makes the second T become B, A (or even Object?)... So T should be B and B extends A so its kinda like A[] a = new A()?

Sorry for my bad english, but I hope you get me :D I just like to check with which Types Java/Eclipse works with and what gets castet implicity by java.

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you have some code that doesn't work? Can you share it and explain what doesn't work?

Comment: Do `C` and `E` play any part in your question? If not, please remove them. There's already enough choss to wade through. And what is `FieldFix`?

Comment: I removed C and E, because they were not important for this example, sorry. FieldFix<T> implements Field<T> and is a Class which stores an Generic Array T[] a; and just has some interface Field<T> methods for int size(), T get(int i) and T set(int i, T e);

I got some different Instructions like A a... and I'd like to check which Type does T becomes.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to know the type of T during eclipse debugging? Or you want to know how all kind of usages of the code works? (Btw, is this your code, or did you copy it from somewhere, or are you continuing working on an existing project with this code? It seems a bit odd you want to understand your own code..)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes, I'd like to know the type of T. Because I got some more Instructions like the A a one and I would like to check if I got the right answer in my head. p.s It's from a course data structures and algorithms, which im taking

Comment: Look at the return type. It's either that or plain `Object`, e.g. in case of the example, T should be A. You can also test setting a `T` by hand like so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297978/calling-static-generic-methods

Comment: @koin Could you add the code for `FieldFix` and `Field`? And perhaps some use-cases you currently don't understand?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I edited some details in my initial post. hope this helps and thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

In your example of calling the method f, the actual value of type T is determined by your first argument - T[] a. In g, it is determined by the actual Field parameters sent.

I managed to view the type of T on runtime by calling and deeply going in the path of: `a.getClass().getGenericInfo().getTree()`.

The reason that the assignment `A a = f(new B[3], ...)` doesn't yield a compiler error lies in the fact that "B is A".

Now, regarding the method g:

You can give the method g a parameter which is a `Field<B>`, call it bField,  for example, and still make the assignment: 
 `A[] a = g(bField, bField)`.

This would work because arrays in java are Invariants: if B extends A than `B[]` extends `A[]`.

If you would have used for example a List instead of array, than a compiler error would have been appeared on the assignment:

```
List<A> goo = goo(bField, bField); //Error: goo cannot be applied to bField...
```

This is because in java Lists are Covariants: even if B extends A, `List<B>` does not extend `List<A>`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to ask yourself, is there any assignment of `T` that will make it valid (there may be multiple valid choices, but what matters is whether there is at least one)? If there is, it should compile.

I am not sure which of the `x0` - `x16` lines you have trouble with. In the later example `A[] a = X.g(new FieldFix<B>(8), new FieldFix<B>(8));` you have these constraints from the parameters and return type:

- `FieldFix<B>` is a subtype of `Field<? extends T>` (i.e. `B` is a subtype of `T`)
- `FieldFix<B>` is a subtype of `Field<? super T>` (i.e. `B` is a supertype of `T`)
- `T[]` is a subtype of `A[]` (i.e. `T` is a subtype of `A`)

The first two constraints already guarantee that only `T` = `B` is valid, and that satisfies the third one also. So it should compile.