# How to cast SubscribeOn result to proper type

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a problem with this code snipet:

```
@Override
    public Single<List<Order>> getOrders() {
        return Single.create(subscriber -> {
            List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
            database.beginTransaction();

            Cursor cursor = database.query(OrdersSqliteTable.TABLE_NAME,
                    null, null, null, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                orders.add(OrdersSqliteTable.cursorToOrder(cursor));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
            database.endTransaction();

            subscriber.onSuccess(orders);
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
```

As you can see, i want to return Single subscribed to io scheduler. Return type - `Single<List<OrderItem>>`, but operator subscribeOn returns `Single<Object>`. Compiler yells at me with "incompatible type" (i'm using Jack compiler for Android) is there any way to cast result of subscribeOn? ("cast" operator do not work, cause it doesn't support generics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with `subscribeOn` just modify `create` call to

```
  return Single.<List<Order>>create(subscriber -> {
  ...
```

For example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297978/calling-static-generic-methods) for details.