# Method to return function with generics

Tags: java, function, generics

```
static <R> Function<Optional<R>,Function<R, Optional<String>>> checkPresence(String err){
        return ro -> r -> ro.map(x -> emptyStrOpt.get())
                            .orElseGet(() -> Optional.of(err));
}
```

```
//toDateOfInjury is Function<Bill,LocalDate>

static final Function<Bill,Optional<String>> dateOfInjuryNotNull = b ->
            toDateOfInjury.andThen(
                    o -> checkPresence("No date of injury").apply(o).apply(b));
```

IntelliJ complains that for o, it expects `Optional<Object>` but it's receiving `Optional<LocalDate>`.

Also, is there any way to declare a function using generics without returning it from a method?

EDIT: for the sake of completeness, let's just say that toDateOfInjury is

```
Function<Bill,Optional<LocalDate>> toDateOfInjury = b -> Optional.ofNullable(LocalDate.now()); //though it map to empty optional too of course
```

EDIT2: After getting past the first problem, I fixed it like so:

```
static final Function<Bill,Optional<String>> dateOfInjuryNotNull2 = b ->
            toDateOfInjury.andThen(
                    o -> EventValidationUtils.<LocalDate>checkPresence("No date of injury").apply(o)).apply(b);

    static <R> Function<Optional<R>,Optional<String>> checkPresence(String err){
        return ro -> ro.map(x -> emptyStrOpt.get())
                            .orElseGet(() -> Optional.of(err));
    }
```

Comment: Please provide full code for details.

Comment: @MajidHajibaba I added a stand-in function for `toDateOfInjury`. `Bill` is just a dto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: [Calling static generic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297978/calling-static-generic-methods)

You need to specify **generic type** (here is *LocaleDate*) when calling a generic method. In your method call it cannot specify method type so inherit it as Object. So you need to specify it like below (Suppose Test is your class name):

```
static final Function<Bill,Optional<String>> dateOfInjuryNotNull = b ->
            toDateOfInjury.andThen(
                    o -> Test.<LocalDate>checkPresence("No date of injury").apply(o).apply(b));
```

But you face other problems need to solve.